# Complex cross layout architecture and separation of concerns

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uikit

I want to implement a cross layout just like Wallapop app does on its main feed.

---

[image]

---

As you can see, it's composed of two groups of cells *(Featured items, Items near you)*. The first group is scrolled horizontally, and the second group is scrolled vertically.

The first UIKit component that came to my mind to make that kind of layout is `UICollectionView`, having one section for each scrolling direction. Unfortunately `UICollectionView` current implementation is very limited, forcing the scroll in one direction only, no matter how many sections you declare.

So I wanted to give it a shot with vanilla UIKit components and that's what I got;

---

[image]

---

The problem with my solution is that the vertical `UICollectionViewController` (highlighted in green) is scrolling on its own and not pushing the horizontal `UICollectionViewController`s upward.

I've also thought about using a single `UICollectionViewController` for the vertical cells, and setting an `UIStackView` with horizontal `UICollectionViewController`s as needed for the horizontal cells, but it's a messy solution and doesn't scale very well, I even couldn't set a title for the vertical cells section If I opt this way.

Ideally, I want each group of scrollable cells to be it's own `UIViewController` in order to have a clear separation of concerns and modularity.

Is there a better way to implement a layout like the one I want with vanilla UIKit components?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the most stable solution is to use the following view hierarchy:

1. Use one `UICollectionView`(1) instance
2. Horizontally scrollable sections can be implemented as **Screen width** `UICollectionViewCell` containing horizontally scrollable `UICollectionView`
3. Vertically scrollable sections should be just a regular section of `UICollectionView`(1)

#### Pros

- UIKit only
- Nothing extraordinary is needed - just a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` everywhere
- Cells are the same for Horizontally scrollable cells and Vertically scrollable cells
- Good scalability and separation of concerns. Independent behaviors of Horizontal and Vertical sections each of which can have multiple data sources.

#### Cons

Horizontally scrollable sections should have fixed height. Otherwise scrolling behavior will be harder to maintain.

#### Arrow on the image means **Uses!**

[image]

Comment: The unique downside I see with this design is that it's not modular. The main `UICollectionView`'s data source must handle the placeholder container cells (for horizontal scrolling) plus the product models, thus not separating each section* on it's own `UIViewController` for better modularity. *(With section I mean each product group _(ie: featured items, items near you in previous my example)_)

Comment: @Tylerian Each design is a matter of a tradeoffs. I agree with you though.

Comment: @Tylerian, for the case of data source handling I can suggest you to watch this [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/) session about AggregateDataSource approach. The example they provide is a bit different from what you need, but you can take the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following way:

A collection view with two cell in it. First cell is for featured items and the second cell is for items near you. The first cell will cover full width and height required by your design.

For scalability use a Container View which embed a `CollectionViewController` which will responsible for showing featured item. This embedded CollectionViewController will scroll horizontally.

Items near you are straight forward direct cell of the initial collection view controller.

So your implementation of featured horizontal collection view remain in the embedded CollectionViewController and the items for cell remains in the primary CollectionViewController which also contain a loose connection (embedding into a container view) to the featured item.

It also does not suffer from the problem like scrolling vertically the items for sale does not scroll up the featured items.

Here is a screenshot which depicts the idea

[image]